# Enum with Raw value, Codable

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift-protocols, codable

The following code doesn't compile:

```
enum Occupation: String {
  case designer = "Designer"
  case engineer = "Engineer"
}

public struct SteveJobs: Codable {
  let name: String
  let occupation: Occupation
}
```

On the other hand, it should compile since the `Occupation` is represented as a `String` which is `Codable`.

Why can't I use `enum` with raw value in `Codable` structs?

**In particular, why automatic conformance isn't working in such a case.**

[image: error]

Comment: Tip: If you click on the red octagons (with the '!'s in), Xcode will show you any notes associated with that diagnostic, in this case: "Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'Occupation' does not conform to 'Decodable'" & "Cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'Occupation' does not conform to 'Encodable'".

Comment: Thanks, in this case it was clear, it's the occupation that was causing the troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic `Codable` synthesis is “opt-in,” i.e. you have to declare the
conformance explicitly:

```
enum Occupation: String, Codable { // <--- HERE
    case designer = "Designer"
    case engineer = "Engineer"
}

public struct SteveJobs: Codable {
    let name: String
    let occupation: Occupation
}
```

See [SE-0166 Swift Archival & Serialization](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md)

> By adopting these protocols, user types opt in to this system.

The same is true for automatic `Hashable` and `Equatable` synthesis,
compare [Requesting synthesis is opt-in](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md#requesting-synthesis-is-opt-in) in SE-0185, where
some reasons are listed:

> - The syntax for opting in is natural; there is no clear analogue in
>     Swift today for having a type opt out of a feature.
> - It requires users to make a conscious decision about the public API
>     surfaced by their types. Types cannot accidentally "fall into"
>     conformances that the user does not wish them to; a type that does not
>     initially support Equatable can be made to at a later date, but the
>     reverse is a breaking change.
> - The conformances supported by a type can be clearly seen by examining
>     its source code; nothing is hidden from the user.
> - We reduce the work done by the compiler and the amount of code
>     generated by not synthesizing conformances that are not desired and
>     not used.